# Pandas extract rows based on condition, but keep old row index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

When extracting rows based on certain condition, I am losing old row indices.

I have a pandas dataframe with a column with numerical values, and I extract all the rows based on the condition below:

```
df = df.loc[df['column_name'] <= 1]
```

The extraction is successful except the new dataframe has new row indices now.

How do I keep the old indices?

Comment: You need to reset row indices.

Comment: what do you mean by new and old indices in this case? can you show explicity what you mean and what you want?

Comment: In other words, the row labels for the rows returned from that selection will be unchanged. Do you want to give them new labels that start from 0 and go to *N*-1?

Comment: @Rheatey Bash reseting row indices would cause the same problem. What I am looking for is keeping the old, not setting new ones. Would you have other recommendations?

Comment: @PaulH, in brief. My old dataframe has row indices of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want my new dataframe to keep that sequence. So, when certain rows are selected, my row indices would be 0,1,2,5, NOT 0,1,2,3. Let me know if that's unclear

Comment: @PaulH. Yes row labels should be "unchanged", but they are being changed in my case. How do you keep them from changing?

Comment: df = df.loc[df['column_name'] <= 1].copy().reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: They shouldn't be changed. I think you need to check your underlying dataset. When I do a similar operation on my machine, they are unchanged

Comment: Boolean indexing does not affect the values of the index as seen in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had just tried to reproduce your question. I believe that you are trying to do something like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,0,1]})
df.head(10)
```

which produces output like below

```
 column_name
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   1
7   1
8   0
9   1
```

Once I run your suggested code `df = df.loc[df['column_name']<=1]`, I had got this with `df.head(10)`

```
column_name
0   1
3   1
6   1
7   1
8   0
9   1
```

which seems to have older indices. In pandas, you need to reset indices to get new one otherwise it does not do automatically.